# How do I provide an image reference in Chicago style?

Tags: citations, chicago-manual-of-style

In my writing, I have used several images which I have collected from different URLs. For example, I have used [this image](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*dh0lzq0QNCOyRlX1Ot4Vow.jpeg), which can be found in [this online article](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-pupalerushikesh-svm-f4b42800e989).

How can I use this image in my writing with an appropriate citation?